# Set authentication token expiry in ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've got a website directly from Microsoft's ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web app template with "Authentication type" set to "Individual Accounts".

How do I set the expiration of the authentication token, preferably with a rolling value?

Comment: If you're using Identity [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#tokens) goes through some scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), you'd add something like the following in:

```cs
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

From the docs about `ExpireTimeSpan`:

> Controls how much time the authentication ticket stored in the cookie will remain valid from the point it is created
> The expiration information is stored in the protected cookie ticket. Because of that an expired cookie will be ignored
> even if it is passed to the server after the browser should have purged it.
>
> This is separate from the value of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions.Expires`, which specifies how long the browser will keep the cookie.

In other words, while it doesn't set the cookie itself with an expiration value, the `ExpireTimeSpan` and `SlidingExpiration` settings will cause the application to provide a new value  in responses around every 5 minutes and update within the protected cookie value the new expiration.

Comment: Musta been typing the wrong thing into Bing. I did that, but I did it before `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity`. Lesson learned, lol. Thanks